Outlook addin - Extension points like Copilot
I am trying to create an Outlook addin and was wondering how copilot has other UI elements in Outlook that allow the user to interact with it.
Below you can see in Outlook Desktop Mac there is a way to open Copilot from an individual message. Not just from the ribbon. And this is what I would like to achieve for my addin.

I can see in outlook web version that my addin can be opened from individual messages. I would love for the desktop version of my addin to be available here too.
Is Copilot just able to do more because it is developed by Microsoft? Is it even an addin or just implemented directly in Outlook itself?
I have searched through the docs and was not able to find anything. It seems as if you just have the MessageReadCommandSurface, MessageComposeCommandSurface etc but no way to tell it where to show exactly. It might just depend on the version of Outlook the user is using.

That is correct. That kind of UI integration is not available through any API exposed by Outlook, neither Web addin nor COM/VSTO on Windows.
